# External regressor always insignificant in GARCH model in R

Tags: r, statistical-significance, garch

My R code:

```
library(rugarch)
rtn<-rnorm(500)
vxr<-rnorm(500)
specgarch <- ugarchspec(variance.model=list(model="sGARCH",
             external.regressors=matrix(vxr)),
             mean.model=list(armaOrder=c(0,0),external.regressors=matrix(vxr)),
             distribution="norm")

garchfit <- ugarchfit(data=rtn, spec=specgarch)
garchfit
#result
Optimal Parameters

vxreg1  0.000000    0.013308   0.000000  1.00000
```

At any set of data I found `vxreg` provides the same result `0.0000` (p-value=1). Kindly help me regarding this problem.

Comment: Have you tried generating a time series that actually has an external variable in the cond. variance equation and then estimating the effect? If you still get a zero coefficient with p-value at 1, that would indicate a genuine problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you generate `rtn` and `vxr` independently and `vxr` does not affect the conditional variance of `rtn` in any way. When you estimate the model and look at the effect of `vxr` on the conditional variance of `rtn`, you naturally find there is no statistically significant effect. This is in line with the true data generating process (there is no effect). If you tried a large number of times, you could finally get a statistically significant result due to pure chance, though.

Comment: if we add external regressor in mean equation R provides the same result as Eviews but when I add external regressor in variance equation it provides the result of 0.0000 (p-value=1) for any set of data which is inconsistent with result of Eviews. when ever i change the data set then also I find the same result 0.000 (p-alue=1) for external regressor but the same data set provides non-zero coefficient from Eviews or Stata.

Comment: @LaxmidharPanda, this is strange. In my experience, "rugarch" package works pretty well. I would be surprised if there was a mistake in the package code that made external variables in the cond. variance equation insignificant by design. Can you repeat your result for artificially generated data where the variable must be significant by construction?

Comment: Estimate   Pr(>|t|)
mxreg1  0.880040    0.000000
vxreg1  0.000000    0.999999

#result from Eviews
    
mxreg1   0.877296  0.0000

vxreg1       -0.013538  0.0111

sir please help me regarding this external regressor problem. sir I can send my data set if you send me any mail ID please.

Comment: @LaxmidharPanda, If you suspect something is wrong with "rugarch", you may contact the package developer. I have done that, he answered. But make sure to provide all the necessary details so that he can replicate the problem.